# How to display customer names in the date cell for php custom schedule calendar

Tags: php, mysql, calendar

[image]

I am trying to build a custom car schedule calendar for car rental company which to show all free days in white on the attachment file and busy days in red color. Till now I succeeded to draw the calendar with correct days and style colors but I want also in the td cell to display the customer names for each reservation. Also if possible to merge reservation cells

This is my working code, but whatever I tried I could not pass customer names in dates array so I could somehow recognize which reservation day is for each customer.

```
$datstart2 = "2017-01-01 00:00:00" ;
$datend2 = "2017-01-31 00:00:00" ;
foreach($cars as $cid){
$query2 = 'select rr.resnumber, DATE_FORMAT( `datestart` , "%Y-%m-%d" ), DATE_FORMAT( `dateend` , "%Y-%m-%d" ), rr.cl_name, rr.totdays from res_cars rc,res_reservations rr where rr.carid="'.$cid.'" and datestart > now() and (datestart BETWEEN "'.$datstart2.'" AND "'.$datend2.'") group by resnumber order by datestart ASC';
$result2=mysql_query($query2) or die($query2);
$num_rows2=mysql_num_rows($result2);

for($j=0;$j<$num_rows2;$j++){
    $row2=mysql_fetch_row($result2);

    $current = strtotime($row2[1]);
    $last = strtotime($row2[2]);
    //here I generate array that contains all busy days between datestart & dateend for each reservation
    while( $current <= $last ){
        $dates1[] = date('Y-m-d', $current);
        $current = strtotime($step, $current);
    }
}
```

//here I generate a new array with all days without reservation for January for the car
    $dates2 array consists all days in the month

```
$emptydays=array_diff($dates2,$dates1);

foreach($dates as $date){
    //here I draw table cell with different styles if the dy is reserved or not
    if(in_array($date,$emptydays)){
        echo '<td class="emptyday">.</td>';
    } else {
       echo '<td class="busyday">X</td>';
    }
}
}
```

The problem is that I wish table cells from type busyday to look like:

```
echo '<td class="busyday">Customer names here</td>';
```

but whatever I tried had no success. Can you guys help me please and show me the correct way to printout the customer names (cl_name) for each reservation and make it look like:

```
echo '<td class="busyday">Customer names here</td>';
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to write objects to the `$dates1`/`$dates` array that contain both the date and the array. This way both properties would be available in your second loop. One to search for the date, and the other to access the name.

First section:

```
$datstart2 = "2017-01-01 00:00:00" ;
$datend2 = "2017-01-31 00:00:00" ;
foreach($cars as $cid){
$query2 = 'select rr.resnumber, DATE_FORMAT( `datestart` , "%Y-%m-%d" ), DATE_FORMAT( `dateend` , "%Y-%m-%d" ), rr.cl_name, rr.totdays from res_cars rc,res_reservations rr where rr.carid="'.$cid.'" and datestart > now() and (datestart BETWEEN "'.$datstart2.'" AND "'.$datend2.'") group by resnumber order by datestart ASC';
$result2=mysql_query($query2) or die($query2);
$num_rows2=mysql_num_rows($result2);

for($j=0;$j<$num_rows2;$j++){
    $row2=mysql_fetch_row($result2);

    $current = strtotime($row2[1]);
    $last = strtotime($row2[2]);
    //here I generate array that contains all busy days between datestart & dateend for each reservation
    while( $current <= $last ){
        $ODateInfo = new stdClass();
        $ODateInfo->date = date('Y-m-d', $current);
        $ODateInfo->name = $row2[4]
        $dates1[] = $ODateInfo;
        date('Y-m-d', $current);
        $current = strtotime($step, $current);
        $datesCompare[] = date('Y-m-d', $current);
    }
}

$emptydays=array_diff($dates2,$datesCompare);
```

Second section:

```
foreach($dates as $date){
    //here I draw table cell with different styles if the dy is reserved or not
    if(in_array($date->date,$emptydays)){
        echo '<td class="emptyday">.</td>';
    } else {
       echo '<td class="busyday">' . $date->name . '</td>';
    }
}
}
```

The final code would look something like this: (Note I was unable to test it, although this should point you in the right direction.)

Let me know if you need anything further.

Regards,

James

Comment: #James, thank you for helping me, this code returns error:
Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in :
fro $emptydays=array_diff($dates2,$dates1);
anu ideas?thanks

Comment: Sure, will figure it out this evening, if you want a quick fix, replace the object with an associative (or simple numeric) array

Comment: I am afraid I am not familiar with classes and can not manage.. Will be very thankful if you look at it, thanks

Comment: OK, I've added the dateCompare array, this will fix the `Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string` error, let me know how you go

Comment: now all the screen is red, draws busy days.. I think the problem is here:
 $datesCompare[] = date('Y-m-d', $current); -> after I printed it I can see full month dates, from 01.01 to 31.01  
Which dates you want to save in this array? Full month dates are already saved in $dates2 array

Comment: That array should contain what dates1 used to hold to facilitate array_diff, can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131365/discussion-between-europeuser-and-james-scott).

Comment: just added screenshot to our chat